# Amazon cognito confirmation issue using link

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I was already implemented amazon signup verification using link and it was working fine, But suddenly from today i'm unable to use that verification link and showing some error please refer attached screen shot
[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, the verification link will expire.

Comment: No, Just now i signup & got verification link

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: I attached scree shot, that is the only error i got, i think it's not coding related so there is no error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this up. It happens when you do not have any OAuth Flows/Scopes configured. This is a recent bug and we are working on a fix.

A workaround is to enable any OAuth flow which will allow it to work.

Thanks,
Meghana

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can you please update me as soon as this bug is fixed.